# is it possible to have realtime semi detailed outlines and inner lines with nodes in 2.91?

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I've decided to use the inverted hull method, but I was wondering is it possible to give abit more detail with some inner lines. I did come a node outline thing, but it's only for 2.9 and for some of the things I have it has to be at least 2.91. So does anyone know how to do this with nodes. Oh, it has to be real time so no compositor and no freestyle.

Something like this but its outdated and doesn't seem like it will be updated.

https://blender-outline-node-docs.netlify.app/

I'm using blender 2.91 and the eevee render engine

Comment: MB lab seems to do this pretty well using the Frenzel node. I might check out their shaders. The project is on GitHub.

Comment: Yea I heard about it and have it. Is there a way to make it abit more detailed cause it does offer some more than inverted hull but not by much.